# node.js + mongodb + 2 different find() queries

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to do 2 find() queries in my code, each on a separate mongo collection. The 'profiles' query works just fine, but when I add in the 'thresholds' query everything breaks and my admin.storeSession never gets called. Any idea what's the issue?

```
var targetCollection = udb.collection('profiles');
    var tc2 = udb.collection('thresholds');

targetCollection.ensureIndex({username: 1}, {unique : true}, function(err){     //set username to unique in 'profiles'
    if (!err){
        targetCollection.find({username: uname}).toArray(function(err, results) {      //search for profile doc that matches username
            if( err || !results.length)     //no document found
                console.error(err);
            else {
                if (bcrypt.compareSync(pw, results[0].password)){       //compare password to hashed bcrypt password in record
                    console.log("login success");
                    admin.storeSession(request, results, function(err){     //store the user's document in the session store
                        if (err)
                            console.error(err);
                    });
                    console.log('MARKER');
                    tc2.find({username: uname}).toArray(function(err, results) {      //search for profile doc that matches username
                        if( err || !results.length)     //no document found
                            console.log(err);
                        else {
                            console.log("Found threshold doc");
                            admin.storeThresholds(request, results, function(err){     //store the user's document in the session store
                                if (err)
                                    console.error(err);
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                    console.log('Password hash does not match in system.');
            }
            response.redirect('/dashboard');
            udb.close();
        });
    }
```

Comment: What precisely is the error that happens when you add the second `find` call?

Comment: I don't get an error, the second query just seems to never get executed. I don't know if you're only supposed to have one query per connection or what, seems strange. I updated the question code, `admin.storeSession()` gets executed, while `admin.storeThresholds` never does. Nothing within that `find()` section is output to console at all.

Comment: Can you confirm the code is called? You certainly can have more than one active query (and in this case, you only have one anyway, as the results were already gathered by the call to `toArray`).

Comment: Which code? I know the first query gets called because the JS function inside gets executed. The entire second part doesn't I think, because none of the console.log messages are output. 'MARKER' is the last thing I see displayed to the console.

Comment: You're closing the connection before the second query has executed it looks like: `udb.close();` It's all async through there, so you'd need to wait for it to finish before closing.

Comment: Indeed I am... that fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: And in long running NodeJS apps, it's better to just leave the connection open. There's no need to close it.